# SignalR connection impossible outside vs project

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I've set up this ASP VS 2013 project in which I'm using signalR.

This works smoothly. Code of the html file:

```
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="SignalR.StockTicker.js"></script>
```

When debugging this, it is hosted on

```
    http://localhost:50408/SignalR.Sample/StockTicker.html
```

Now I'm trying to do the same in a Non VS project.

So I've changed the script source :

```
    <script src="imported/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:50408/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="imported/SignalR.StockTicker.js"></script>
```

But this doesn't work when running. Even after specifying the url in the js code

```
 $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:50408/signalr/hubs';

 $.connection.hub.start()
```

or even without /signalr/hubs

```
 $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:50408/signalr/';
```

But All I get is a blank screen.

What could be wrong here?

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean "in a Non VS project", is this running on IIS express ?

Comment: @bedane no, just an html file in another folder. I'm sorry if I'm making a crucial mistake here, I'm entirely new to ASP , signalR etc

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a web server for processing user requests! SignalR establishes a long-running connection between an user's browser and a web server. 
[More info](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr)

When running the web application in Visual Studio, VS actually starts a web server which hosts your signalR hub. If you're going to deploy your web application, you need a web server. [Example.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038)

Comment: But when I'm running the vs project, using the exact same js files, and allowing crossdomain, it should be possible to acces that server from every file in my drive, right? Or am I missing sth here?